# Add a db field in query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query,i want to add a field in this query,I am stuck where to put this field i-e proper place.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table-name`(".substr($columns,0,-2).") VALUES (".substr($values,0,-2).");");
```

Field name to add email with there value $email.

Comment: Could you echo out $columns and show everyone what it says?

Answer (score 0):

By using this you can insert any number of values into a table

```
INSERT INTO `table-name` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`,...) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $columns and $values variables must be some sort of delimited strings. You'll need to update whatever mechanism is controlling those variables or else just add your email field to the end like this:

```
INTO `table-name`(".substr($columns,0,-2).", email) VALUES (".substr($values,0,-2).", '".$email."');");
```